# VScode can't find module when importing folder

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I have this structure:

```
├ reducers/
│  └ index.ts
└ store/
   └ configureStore.ts
```

In configureStore.ts i have:

```
import rootReducer from '../reducers';
```

and vscode complaining that he cannot find module '../reducers'
changing import to

```
import rootReducer from '../reducers/index'
```

fixing this error.

Is it OK behavior?

Answer (score 5):

I have found the cause of my problem. In tsconfig.json there was a missing line

```
"module": "commonjs",
```